# How to extend system drive in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-esxi

I have virtual machine (VMware vCenter 4.0) using Windows Server 2003. I would like to extend C:-drive. I can see the unallocated space in C:-drive (disk management). How to do that in Windows Server 2003?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been asked before and would have come up in the previous questions list as you typed this questions.

I'd suggest using a [GPARTD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) live boot CD image.

Answer (score 4):

Dell have provided an command line extender utility called [ExtPart.exe](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R64398&formatcnt=2&fileid=83929) that will grow the C: drive on Windows 2003 servers without downtime. They wont provide any support for it if it goes wrong though and you should bear in mind that Microsoft don't support any mechanism for growing system partitions on Windows 2003 so you need to be happy to accept that you will be on your own if something goes wrong down the line.

I've used this in labs and test environment for quite some time and have had no issues with it but I've never left a server that I used this on running for an extended period of time. Some applications fail to notice that the volume size has changed after this has run so a reboot is a good idea even if its not absolutely required.

Comment: Tried multiple times, great result. No downtime. Great tool.

Answer (score 0):

Acronis Disk Director is also another option, not free, but very effective and popular.

Answer (score -1):

diskpart is the panacea, and it is with Windows...

http://blog.petecheslock.com/2009/04/07/how-to-extend-windows-boot-volumes-in-vmware/

Comment: Some futher details? The link might dissapear a any time.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.